# Animate View in Fragment with FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-resources

I usually use [FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to specify fragment's entering and returning transition animations. For as much as I understand, the animation passed to the method can only be applied to the whole fragment view. I can tell the whole fragment to slide/fade in or out etc.

Haveing transaction from fragment A to B, is it possible to specify animation, so that upon replace, a specific view within fragment B gets animated? Let's say I want this view to travel from point X to Y and I want to specify this behaviour in resources passed to `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit)`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int)) applies animation to the [`Window`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) of your `Activity`. Thus, views that are inside your `Fragment` cannot be animated. You have to switch to [`Transition`](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) animations.